# Should I ground the unused pins of an oscillator crystal?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, crystal

I have seen in this example circuit of an RTC where the unused legs of an oscillator crystal are grounded. I will be using an [ECS EXC SMD crystal](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ecx-306x.pdf) and from what I thought the unused pins are better left disconnected to the circuit and are just there for structural connection to the board.

Am I wrong or is this example circuit I am using doing it incorrectly?

[image: ?]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [4-Lead SMD Crystal - Connect Both GNDs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390060/4-lead-smd-crystal-connect-both-gnds)

Comment: Is this a *crystal* or a *crystal oscillator*?

Comment: @Hearth Figure 1 top right drawing is telling what it is. Had some trouble to find it too...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, yes, though you mean top right I believe.

Comment: Yes, you should, it will reduce the chances of the oscillator turning into an unintentional radiator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic from the datasheet shows those two pins simply connected together.  And this is a plastic housing.  So it doesn't much matter.

Usually when the part has a metal case, one or more of the unused pins is connected to the enclosure of the part, so in that case connecting them to ground will provide some shielding and prevent some radiation as @Voltage Spike mentions.